# Is it possible to perform joins across different databases using LINQ?

Tags: c#, database, linq, join

Is it possible to perform joins across different databases using LINQ? If yes then how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the databases are on the same server, you can create views (and 3 part naming) so that all the tables are queryable from one database.

If the databases are on different servers, you can use linked servers and views (and 4 part naming) so that all the tables are queryable from one database.

Comment: +1 - this is my preferred answer and a tecnnique I've used a few times now in emergencies :)

Comment: This should really be flagged as the proper answer. You immediately are managing multiple context/model connection strings and more complex linq queries for no reason with the current accepted answer.

Comment: It's also possible to use 3 part naming in the table attribute.

Answer (score 0):

calling .ToList() is querying all the records in db, so it will eat a lot of memory if there are a lot of records in tables.

Or try this one [The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332920/the-specified-linq-expression-contains-references-to-queries-that-are-associated).

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), as well as mention side-notes like performance considerations in comments. Until then, posting links or commentary as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted.

Comment: I should say it is kind of duplicate question, right?
Thanks!