# Multiple Context joining c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net MVC application, there are two contexts I have linked with my system.

In my controller, I have mentioned it as

```
private zSqlDb db = new zSqlDb();

private DatabaseZSql dbs = new DatabaseZSql();
```

So I want to connect some table from both contexts and I wrote this code to link it and get the data.

```
var EmpDetails = (from e in db.CreateEmployee 
join dep in db.Department on e.DepId equals dep.Id 
join des in db.Designation on e.DesignId equals des.Id 
join emDetails in dbs.EmpDetails on e.Id equals emDetails.EmpID 
join supervisor in db.Employee on emDetails.EmpID equals supervisor.Id
where e.Id == UId select new {
  e.Id,
    e.EmpNo,
    e.EmpName,
    dep.Department,
    des.Designation,
    emDetails.BasicSalary,
    emDetails.EmpCatagory,
    emDetails.EmpGrade,
    emDetails.YearOfService,
    SupervisorName = supervisor.EmpName
});
```

When I debug the code I got an error ```The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.``

Comment: Separate into 2 different query. First query handle `db` and store the data into memory. Then use the stored data to join `dbs`.

Comment: hi @YongShun thing is that the db1 has the total employee details. One of tables in db2 has the employee Id. So I Need to connect those 2 to get the emp details. Separating the queries I won't think can do this. If can do, can you show me an example ?

Comment: First, you should pull all `employee Ids` from `db2` so now you have all `Id List` now loop the details from the `Id List` on db context1. You should this way. We cannot execute query combining two context at the same time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Linq` does not allow you to `query` tables that are from different `contexts`

So try to fetch all the related data from one context first. Then query that data with the second context. The `.AsEnumerable()` part is crucial.

```
var firstContext = (from e in db.CreateEmployee 
                 join dep in db.Department on e.DepId equals dep.Id 
                 join des in db.Designation on e.DesignId equals des.Id 
                 join supervisor in db.Employee on e.Id equals supervisor.Id
                 where e.Id == UId select new { 
                 e.Id
                 e.EmpNo,
                 e.EmpName,
                 dep.Department,
                 des.Designation,
                 SupervisorName = supervisor.EmpName).AsEnumerable();

var empDetails = (from emDetails in dbs.EmpDetails 
                 join e in firstContext on emDetails.EmpID equals e.Id
                 select new {
                        e.Id,
                        e.EmpNo,
                        e.EmpName,
                        e.Department,
                        e.Designation,
                        emDetails.BasicSalary,
                        emDetails.EmpCatgory,
                        emDetails.EmpGrade,
                        emDetails.YearOfService,
                        SupervisorName = e.EmpName
                 });
```

For more information visit [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332920/error-the-specified-linq-expression-contains-references-to-queries-that-are-as)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @YongShun and @mdfariduddinkiron. I wrote this and this worked

```
 var EmpMain = db.CreateEmployee.Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList();
            var Department = db.CreateDepartment.Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList();
            var Dessignation = db.CreateDesignation.Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList();
            var EmpDtils = dbs.EmpDetails.ToList();
            var MixDetails = (from e in EmpMain
                              join d in Department on e.DepId equals d.Id
                              join de in Dessignation on e.DesignId equals de.Id
                              join ma in EmpDtils on e.Id equals ma.EmpID
                              join sup in EmpMain on ma.Id equals sup.Id
                              where e.Id == UId

                              select new
                              {
                                  e.Id,
                                  e.EmpNo,
                                  e.EmpName,
                                  d.Department,
                                  de.Designation,
                                  ma.BasicSalary,
                                  ma.EmpCatagory,
                                  ma.EmpGrade,
                                  ma.YearOfService,
                                  SupName =sup.EmpName

                              });
```

Comment: But now you're pulling your entire tables into your application memory, and are performing the join in your application process instead of letting the database do what it's good at. Why do you have two contexts to begin with?

Comment: @CodeCaster it because, There is a system in the company that holds the employee master details. So for this app I need to get details from that database table to show the employee names and details. Thats why need to connect to two different contexts

Comment: Yes yes, "microservices" all the way. Do you understand the rest of what I wrote? You could at least just select the IDs, instead of pulling the entire tables. And for _your_ tables (db.Create...), you don't need the `ToList()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's a good point. I will do the same. Thank you very much for the idea. :)