# "Join 2 tables" on different servers via in memory variables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Does joining two tables on different servers need a linked server, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278993/is-it-possible-to-perform-joins-across-different-databases-using-linq)? The DBA group controls these server objects, and they don't want to create an excessive number of linked servers.

Is it good to "join" two tables on different servers by first reading one into memory as a variable, and potentially running another query on another server with the variable from the first?

Using C# to access SQL server `SERVER_A`, and then getting all records from table `TABLE_A`, we save it to an collection variable, say `VARIABLE_A`.
Then we could connect to SQL server `SERVER_B`, run a select query on `TABLE_B` with this variable `VARIABLE_A` and try to get the join result of `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`.

Will this solution achieve the desired results (that is function, and not require additional linked servers)?

Comment: you can use [linked servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to join across tables in different dbs on different servers no need for temp variable.

Comment: DBAs are there to support the programming effort.  While they may have good reason to throw up some roadblocks when it comes to creating a linked server connection, their ultimate answer must be for the good of the company/project.  Get your thoughts together and present your arguments clearly to them.

Comment: And no, in-memory joins are a *terrible* idea.

Comment: The short answer is "You cannot run a select query on `TABLE_B` using `VARIABLE_A`".  How many rows do you need to pull down from `TABLE_B` on average?

Comment: Size of TABLE_A and TABLE_B are ~100K records.

Comment: You most definitely need linked servers based on the amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-memory joins (from the application) are a *terrible* idea.  It would require (at best) reading in the entire table, or (at worst) doing a read from the second server for each row returned from the first.

Both of these methods increase the memory overhead, application complexity, and network usage.

The **linked server** option would be my `first choice`.

A *far* distant `second choice` would be to use replication and replicate the second server's database to the first server.  Then you could do an in-server join between databases.

Comment: Thanks. I'll come and ask DBA again!