# (Linq/Lambda) Join 2 or more tables with 2 DBContext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Im Getting error like this: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

```
var employee = new ApplicationDbContext().Employee;
var otherTable = new OtherDbContext().OtherTable;

var returnValue = (from e in employee
                        join o in otherTable on e.Id equals o.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            e.Name,
                            e.Address,
                            o.Others
                        });
```

Any Solution/s?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can join across two contexts. EF has to convert that to a SQL query somehow

Comment: Not possible to query both contexts at once, see this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278993/is-it-possible-to-perform-joins-across-different-databases-using-linq

Comment: Is there are a lot of data at Employee or OtherTable?

Comment: The comments are correct. Note that the join method's inner Type will be IEnumerable anyway, so just load the entities of the 2nd context (inner) to an IEnumerable<otherTable> variable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534644(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Somehow, soon it will have a lot of data. So i think the performance will suffer if I query all the records in 2nd context(something like .ToList()).
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instantiate your DBContext generally and don't specify a table/model. 
Example:

```
 private ApplicationDBContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Then choose if you're still going to use LINQ or Raw SQL. I believe you're more familiar with SQL because you mentioned joining tables so why not use that? [Here's a tutorial on how to use Raw SQL.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application)

[If you still insist in using LINQ and involve join, here's a good reference for it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: All the queries in project is using linq or lambda, it will be unform if I use raw sql in this particular query.
Thanks!

Comment: It will be more good enough if we do it on [SP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) and create a [linked server](http://forums.asp.net/t/1254974.aspx?How+to+join+tables+from+different+databases+in+SQL+select+statement+) instead calling `.ToList()` that caused to query it all. So I'll accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bets solution is to have one DbContext with the two entities with.  This way EF can easily join between them.  You can create 2 more, distinct entities with just the fields you want.  If your concerned about maintaining duplicative types, consider creating interfaces between them (SOLID's interface segregation principal).  This way if you alter a property of field, do it first via the interface and it will force you to correct the duplicative types.

Assuming you cannot alter your existing ApplicationDbContext & OtherDbContext, you can create a third DbContext and 2 duplicative models this way:

```
interface IEmployee { string Name { get; } string Address { get; } }
interface IOtherTable { IEnumerable Others { get; } }
public class Employee : IEmployee { /* your existing class that may have more field*/ }
public class OtherTable : IOtherTable { /* your existing class that may have other fiels*/ }

public class Employee2 : IEmployee { /* Making this a subclass in a controller or something is preferred */ }
public class OtherTable2 : IOtherTable { /* Making this a subclass in a controller or something is preferred */ }
public sealed class CombinedDbContext {
    public DbSet<Employee2> { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherTable2> { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do this safely and without hacky code...

```
var con = new CombinedDbContext();
var employee = con.Employee;
var otherTable = con.OtherTable;

var returnValue = (from e in employee
                    join o in otherTable on e.Id equals o.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        e.Name,
                        e.Address,
                        o.Others
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Employee> empList = new ApplicationDbContext().Employee.ToList();
List<OtherTable> othrList= new OtherDbContext().OtherTable.ToList();

var returnValue = (from e in empList 
                        join o in othrList on e.Id equals o.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            e.Name,
                            e.Address,
                            o.Others
                        });
```

try this it will work.....

Comment: Thanks for response!
.ToList() is querying all the records, so maybe it will be stressful to query it all.
what do you think?
Other solution?

Comment: Manish,

Thanks, but its a bad idea to instantiate every entity just to do a join.